# Angular view doesn't show for a ui-router state with no url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to display some view, on any calling URL.

```
$stateProvider.state('test', {
        url: '',
        views: {
            'testView@' : {
                templateUrl: '/app/test/test.html',
                controller: 'test.controller',
                controllerAs: 'testVM'
            }
        }
    });
```

I've tried `url: ''` and with no url attribute, but my view is never displayed. It only works when it has a specific url like `url: '/'`

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Mock App</title>
        <!-- Import additional "vendor" css here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/styles/bundle-GENERATED-VERSION.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div data-ui-view="testView"></div>

        <script src="app/bundle-GENERATED-VERSION.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: what do you mean by any calling URL ?

Comment: you can try something like url:'/*path' 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.
One last question, how can I trigger my view's controller to be called every time I modifiy a parameter in my URL (without having to refresh completely the page) ?

Comment: adding my comment as an answer, also for your second question, you can ask another question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match every url that starts with `/`

you can try something like `url:'/*path'`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters